# A part of my model disappears when i enter edit mode

Tags: modeling

Pretty much the title. Here's some screenshots:

Object mode:
[image]

Edit mode:
[image]

Luckily I'm done and it still exports like normal. What caused this? Is there a fix?

Comment: Press Alt+H to unhide the hidden vertices

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot. I thought I tried that, but it must have been in object mode. Thanks again!